# Facebook Like plugin not showing on Chrome, just for one website

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, facebook-like

I am using the facebook like plugin on www.ibmarketingdigital.com.br and it works fine.
I tried to use it on www.weshare.net.br and it does not work on Chrome or Internet Explorer, only on firefox.
I generated the code, using facebook developers plugin page.

The thing is, if I open on Chrome this URL
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/ibsistemas

it works just fine.

however, if I open this other one:
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/WeShareCoworking

it doesn't show anything on Chrome or IE.

Does anyone knows how to fix it? Apparently it's just the second one that doesn't work properly.

Thanks in advance,
Fernando

Comment: it does work on Firefox though

Comment: I can see both like boxes in chrome.

Comment: which version of chrome are you using? Thing is that is not showing on mine and on my developer's laptop, which is really weird. Could you make a print of it on chrome and/or IE?

Comment: Chrome version: Version 24.0.1312.57 m   OS: Windows 7

Comment: but the last link doesn't show anything on IE9 on Windows 7

Comment: See the screenshots @ http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/2686/sodemo.png